# Unstable Spark Application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I have a program as follows. First, I read the data

```
val data = sc
  .textFile("...")
  .map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt))
  .map(x => (x(0), x(1)))
  .groupBy(new HashPartitioner(sc.defaultParallelism))
  .persist()
data.count()
```

Then, I run some algorithms on `data`. The code is not allowed to be made public.

```
val beg = System.currentTimeMillis

// run some algorithms on "data"
...
...

val end = System.currentTimeMillis
println((end - beg) / 1000.0)
```

Here is my question. I observed that if I ran the same Spark program under the *same input* and *same configuration* multiple times, the observed running times were quite different. For example, some took only 100 seconds, while some took about 600 seconds. In my opinion, `data` is created by `groupBy` the same keys. Therefore, each time I feed the same input, `data` should always be the same. Moreover, my program has no other randomness sources. Therefore, I should have observed stable running time. I tried to debug this and found that sometimes there were short GCs and sometimes there were very long GCs. I wonder why this happens. Wouldn't the garbage collection behavior be the same across different runs?

Comment: Also, there is data locality and shuffling needed. That can change your time.